# How can I let users draw a UIImage mask?

Tags: ios, uiimage, ciimage

I would like to implement functionality in my app where users can paint their own custom image masks. I know how to mask a UIImage with another UIImage using `CGImageCreateWithMask` but how could I let users paint the mask?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30273899/drawing-uiimage-mask-with-gesturerecognizer?rq=1 maybe is an start point for you

Comment: Thanks. I think `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` was what I was looking for

Comment: But should I be starting a new Image Context every time a touch moves?